# Install/setup image magic in Hybris?

Tags: image, imagemagick, content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

I have Image Magic installed in my Mac.
How do I setup Image Magic for Hybris?
Please suggest what are the properties that I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8beda241866910148f8bf99b4994733f.html

and here

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c0f10e6866910149f9eb77dd7e7250a.html?q=media%20conversion

and here 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8b3669cc86691014b42abc07ad88d80f.html?q=media%20conversion

Answer (score 2):

After image magic installation, you need to configure below parameters in your config/local.properties file.

```
imagemagick.bindir=/Users/MyUser/ImageMagick-7.0.3/bin/
imagemagick.configuration.directory=/Users/MyUser/ImageMagick-7.0.3/etc/ImageMagick-7/
```